# Cross compiling smbclient for embedded linux

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, samba

could you please advise me where to download and how to cross compile the smbclient for an embedded linux. Many thanks

Comment: some addition - i need to use toolchain from external supplier

Comment: `configure --help` might help, if it uses autotools.

Comment: thanks, samba is compiled using waf, not autotools

Comment: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Waf#cross-compiling

Comment: thank you, i saw this but did not understand how it works

Comment: What does it mean CC=arm-linux-gnu-gcc waf configure --cross-compile --cross-answers=arm.txt